# Execution failed for task ':whisper.rn:buildNdkBuildDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, speech-to-text, openai-whisper

I am new to coding and I am trying to create my first React Native app. The app should be able to receive audio files from other apps and transcribe them to text. I am combining two existing projects: https://github.com/mybigday/whisper.rn and https://github.com/dimaportenko/react-native-receive-share-file-tutorial.

However, when I try to build the project, I receive the error "Execution failed for task ':whisper.rn:buildNdkBuildDebug[arm64-v8a]'." How can I resolve this issue? Please let me know if you need more information or if I can share the app. Thank you.

my code:
https://github.com/ItamatBuzy/TextToSpeachReactNativeApp

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.